# How to hide a program with the ability to open it again?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, win32gui, win32con

I have a console application written in python using `pyinstaller`. I need the program window to be hidden (if the user specified it), but at the same time it continued to work in the background, and when you click on the icon again, the previously hidden window just showed.
Usually such applications are displayed on the taskbar when you click on the arrow with the text - show hidden icons.

[image]

```py
import win32gui
import win32con


def main():
    while True:
        c_out = input(f"Enter command: ")
        if c_out.lower() == 'hide':
            window('hide')


def window(mode: str):
    the_program_to_hide = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    if mode == 'show':
        win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide, win32con.SW_SHOW)
    else:
        win32gui.ShowWindow(the_program_to_hide, win32con.SW_HIDE)


main()
```

Comment: You mean, like, minimizing it?

Comment: well hide it and leave it to work in the background

Comment: You can certainly change `SW_SHOW` and `SW_HIDE` to `SW_RESTORE` and `SW_MINIMIZE`, but that assumes that your terminal window is the foreground window.  You don't have any guarantee that will be true.  It's a gamble.  Console apps in Windows don't own their window.  That belongs to the shell.

Comment: I need to hide it exactly, and when I click on the exe file on the desktop again to show the running application again, re-read the question